How can I update a Bootstrap 5 popover when it's not visible?
I'm using Bootstrap 5.3, and I'd like to update the content of a popover when it's not visible. This works before it's shown the first time, but once it's hidden the first time it seems like it might be removed from the DOM. After this I'm unable to find it with a selector.
Is there a recommended way to make popovers accessible to JS even when they're not visible? There's a lot of ways to work with popovers so here's a short sample of what I'm doing:
<span id="my-popover-trigger" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="click">click me</span>

<div id="my-connector-popover-host" style="display:none">
    <div id="my-popover">
        content goes here
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#my-popover-trigger').popover({animation: false, html: true, content: $('#my-popover')});
    });
</script>

I can access my popover content with $('#my-popover') before it's hidden the first time, but not after that.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#methods

I had to look through the Bootstrap source to confirm - but the popover content is indeed removed from the DOM (in tooltip.js hide()). The Popover object keeps a reference to it in order to show it again later.
So I just need to keep a reference to it (e.g. in a global variable var myPopover = $('#my-popover')) in order to update it after it's hidden the first time.
